# Victorian-era science fiction novel about sound altering our consciousness?

Tags: story-identification, novel

It was a rather short novel, or a long story, where a couple or a man travels to
an unknown rural area in England for some work with high pay. The master of that place is trying to reach the frequency of God by complicated sound experiments. I can't remember the name. I think it was published around 1890 to 1920.

Comment: When did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: 1890s to 1920s i guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Human Chord](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6149884-the-human-chord) by Algernon Blackwood:

> As a boy, Robert Spinrobin created vast worlds in his imagination, naming and bringing things to life. In later years this inner world of childhood fades, but he retains the mystical vision of the poet. Bored and disappointed by his humdrum adult existence, and seeking an adventure of the soul, he comes across a strange advertisement in a newspaper. Attracted by the promise of adventure, he travels to the remote mountains of Wales where he is to assist Philip Skale in his enigmatic ‘experiments in sound’. Caught up in the mystical adventure he has yearned for, Robert begins to feel in touch with the greater elemental scheme of the universe.

It was published in 1928 so it's a bit later than Victorian, but it has that period feel.

Comment: yes thanks!!!!!